# Will this be considered a bad React Context Practise

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am just starting out with react and trying as much as possible to prevent rerenders, thereby using less useState. Would updating my context this way opposed to using a reducer be termed bad practise? What are the pit falls of structuring it this way?

```
import React from "react";



export const DataContext  = React.createContext();

initialData = {
    sGross: 0,
    sExpenses: 0,
    sPension: 0,
  
  };


export const DataProvider= ({children}) =>{
    const updateData = (newData, name) => {
       initialData[name] = newData
     
        }
        
    return (
    <DataContext.Provider  value={{initialData, updateData}}>
        {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
)}
```

Comment: Context provides a way to pass data **through the component tree** without having to pass props down manually at every level check doc : https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext

Comment: to prevent rerenders and infinite loop you can use hooks like useeffect, usecallback, usememo check doc https://www.datainfinities.com/20/too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-renders-to-prevent-an-infinite-loop

Comment: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/usememo-and-usecallback/

Comment: The main problem with this approach is that components and hooks using initialData won't be able to react to changes to it. The data will only change when something else triggers a re-render. I would just use a useState in this situation.

Comment: i send answer with a full example to how to use createContext and useState to show and update a context data... note i use typescript  but you can delete all typescript and keep javascript code

Answer (score 0):

The method you describe will not trigger a re-render even if the data changes... For best performance, you can use memo and callback hooks to create  your context.

and for more performance and preventing unnecessary re-rendering you can use context splitting just like so :

```
// we suppose that a component A need only sGross and a component B need sExpenses & sPension
context = {
    sGross: 0,
    sExpenses: 0,
    sPension: 0,
};

// then you can split the context into 2 context
contextA = {
    sGross: 0,
};

contextB = {
    sExpenses: 0,
    sPension: 0,
};
```

You can check this example to how to use createcontext to share an **auto increment counter** between 3 components using memo and callback hooks :

```
import React, { createContext, useCallback } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

type TDataContext = {
  contextData: TData;
  setContextData: (data: TData) => void;
};

type TData = {
  counter: number;
};

const initialData: TData = {
  counter: 0
};

const DataContext = createContext<TDataContext | null>(null);

const DataProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<TData>(initialData);
  const setContextData = React.useCallback(
    (newState: TData) => {
      setData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, ...newState }));
    },
    [setData]
  );
  const getContextValue = React.useMemo(
    () => ({ contextData: data, setContextData }),
    [data, setContextData]
  );

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={getContextValue}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};
const ShowTimerOne: React.FC<{ counter: number }> = ({ counter }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Component One : Show Counter From props</div>
      <div>{counter}</div>
    </>
  );
};
const ShowTimerFour: React.FC = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Component Four rendred");
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div>Component Four </div>
    </>
  );
};
const ShowTimerTwo: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({ children }) => {
  const { contextData, setContextData } = React.useContext(
    DataContext
  ) as TDataContext;
  return (
    <>
      <div>Component Two : Show Counter From context</div>
      <div>{contextData.counter}</div>

      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
};
const ShowTimerThree: React.FC = () => {
  const { contextData, setContextData } = React.useContext(
    DataContext
  ) as TDataContext;
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Component Three : Show Counter From context and it is child of component
        Two
      </div>
      <div>{contextData.counter}</div>
    </>
  );
};

const SetTimer: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({ children }) => {
  const { contextData, setContextData } = React.useContext(
    DataContext
  ) as TDataContext;
  const Ref = React.useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | string | number | undefined>(
    undefined
  );

  const incrementCounter = useCallback(() => {
    const counter = contextData.counter + 1;
    setContextData({ counter: counter });
  }, [contextData, setContextData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Ref.current === undefined) {
      Ref.current = setInterval(incrementCounter, 1000);
    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(Ref.current);
      Ref.current = undefined;
    };
  }, [incrementCounter]);

  return <ShowTimerOne counter={contextData.counter} />;
};

const App = () => (
  <DataProvider>
    <ShowTimerFour />
    <SetTimer />
    <ShowTimerTwo>
      <ShowTimerThree />
    </ShowTimerTwo>
  </DataProvider>
);

export default App;
```

you can see it in action at :

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-18-playground-forked-hlhhm9?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: The components that utilises the context have a form that rerenders and calls the Provider onSubmit, thereby able to get the present value and use that for further calculations.  My app work has expected, but i needed clarifications on if the use of objects assignement with context and without a reducer is bad?    A code that works doesnt necessarily translates to good code, if you get me.   I have never seen context used in the way i have, i had my reasons for using them this way - abstraction, but wanted another eye.